# ajax and history.replaceState issue

Tags: php, ajax, url, browser

Am trying to load content from another page using ajax and change the browser URL to the new content and here is the code

index.php page:

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
  loadContent($(this).attr('data-page'),$(this).attr('data-query'));
});
  
function loadContent(d1,d2){
  if (d2 == ''){
    history.replaceState(null,'','/example/'+d1);
  }
  else{
    //    this is the issue cause
    history.replaceState(null,'','/example/'+d1+'/'+d2);
  }
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'get-contents.php',
    data: {data1: d1, data2: d2},
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    success: function(data){
      $('.content').html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" data-page="page1" data-query="">load page without query</button>
<button class="btn" data-page="page1" data-query="query">load page with query</button>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Get content page code (get-contents.php):

```
include($_POST['data1'].'.php');
```

The included page code (page1.php):

```
if (isset($_POST['data2']) && $_POST['data2'] != ''){
    echo $_POST['data2'];
}
else{
    echo 'not set';
}
```

When press (load page without query) button,
The output will be:

```
//content
not set
// browser url
localhost/example/page1
```

When press (load page with query) button,
The output will be:

```
//content
// <<<<<<<nothing is happen and this is the problem>>>>
// browser url
localhost/example/page1/query
```

If I commented the line:

```
//history.replaceState(null,'','/example/'+d1+'/'+d2);
```

The content will be loaded successfully, What is wrong with this line.

I wish I had made it well.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

It's done by using history.pushstat with empty url before calling the ajax
And call history.replaceState at success:{}

```
function loadContent(d1,d2){
   history.pushState({},'','');
   $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'get-contents.php',
      data: {data1: d1, data2: d2},
      contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
      success: function(data){
         $('.content').html(data);
         if (d2 == ''){
            history.replaceState({},'','/example/'+d1);
         }
         else{
            history.replaceState({},'','/example/'+d1+'/'+d2);
         }
      }
   });
}
```

I don't know if it's the best solution but it's work for me, And I wanted to share it.